# cakephp Image helper works locally but not online

Tags: php, html, image, cakephp

I have an issue with showing an image via cakephp's image helper. The url of the image is stored in the database as: companiesLogos/defaultLogo.jpg and the code I am using to display that image is `<?php echo $this->Html->image($user['User']['img_path'], array('class' => 'img-circle', 'style' => 'width:50px')); ?>`

It's rendered in the browser for the local version as `<img src="/websites/Gimble/img/companiesLogos/defaultLogo.jpg" class="img-circle" style="width:50px" alt="">` where the url is http://localhost:8080/websites/websitename/DashBoard

It's rendered in the browser for the online version as `<img src="/img/companiesLogos/defaultLogo.jpg" class="img-circle" style="width:50px" alt="">` where the url is http://app.websitename.com.au/DashBoard

Here are a couple of images for both enviroments, the local first then the online version. The online version is sitting on a linux server while the local version is on a windows computer.

What am I missing?

[image: local version]
[image: online version]

Comment: does image exists over `app/webroot/img/companiesLogos/defaultLogo.jpg` ?

Comment: @kamalpal yes it does

Comment: Is the website in a subfolder and not in the root of your hosting?

Comment: @ДејанИгњатов Yes it is in a subfolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use define document root directory where locate your source code.  I think is well explained here: 
How does RewriteBase work in .htaccess

n my own words, after reading the docs and experimenting:

A production installation is a more flexible way to setup CakePHP. Using this method allows an entire
domain to act as a single CakePHP application. This example will help you install CakePHP anywhere on
your filesystem and make it available at http://www.example.com. Note that this installation may require
the rights to change the DocumentRoot on Apache webservers.
Unpack the contents of the CakePHP archive into a directory of your choice. For the purposes of this
example, we assume you chose to install CakePHP into /cake_install. Your production setup will look like
this on the filesystem:

```
/cake_install/
    app/
    webroot/ (this directory is set as the ‘‘DocumentRoot‘‘
    directive)
    lib/
    plugins/
    vendors/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    README
```

Developers using Apache should set the DocumentRoot directive for the domain to:

```
DocumentRoot /cake_install/app/webroot
```

f your web server is configured correctly, you should now find your CakePHP application accessible at
http://www.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is in the root folder of the application (/img does not point to the cakephp root, but to the hosting root). In every .htaccess file (root of cakephp, app and webroot folder) add this line below RewriteEngine on:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder_name/
```